# Copy the last word from a line above the cursor?

Tags: display, terminal, tmux

Sometimes I wish I could copy the last word (separated by spaces) from the line above the one I'm currently working on. Consider the scenario:

```
> aws s3 ls s3://some-bucket | grep 2019-06
2019-06-04 20:25:17 2073695507 some-file-with-too-long-name.tar
>
```

After the command executes, my cursor is at the `>` in the last line and what I'd soon like to do is:

> aws s3 cp s3://some-bucket/**some-file-with-too-long-name.tar**

I feel like I'm wasting time using mouse or screen's copy feature while a specific copy-paste hotkey would do better.

Is there a way I could achieve that using any of the terminals or multiplexers, e.g. Screen or Tmux?

Answer (score 2):

With tmux you can set up a binding to enter copy mode, move the cursor up a line, find the first space, copy from there to the end of line into a buffer, then paste that buffer into your input. Put something like this in your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key '.' copy-mode\; \
 send-keys -X cursor-up\; \
 send-keys -X previous-space\; \
 send-keys -X copy-end-of-line\; \
 paste-buffer
```

then you can type the prefix key (control-b by default) and dot to run the commands. Tested on version 2.6, earlier versions may not have all the required features.